# Illustrator: how to merge multiple gradients

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, gradient

Is it possible to merge multiple gradients into one object?

For example: a rectangle with two radial gradients in two corners. How can I implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add multiple gradient fills to an object via the Appearance panel.

If you need more complex gradients you can use the Mesh Tool to create a gradient mesh. Simply click on a point with the Mesh Tool to create a mesh from the object, you can then change the color of each individual point.

A simply rectangle with each corner point set to a different color:

[image]

For more complex gradients just keep adding points:

[image]

You can expand an existing gradient fill to a gradient mesh by selecting the object, expanding (*Object → Expand*) and selecting "Gradient Mesh":

[image]

- [**Create and edit mesh objects in Illustrator - Adobe Support**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/meshes.html)

Answer (score 5):

One object can have multiple gradients as seen in the image 1 (below).

To add multiple gradients, open your appearances panel and duplicate the fill. Note that the second gradient has to have a blending mode or transparency for this to work.

[image]

**Image 1**: Two radial gradients in same object.

Comment: E.g. a rectangle with two radial gradients in two corners. How can I implement that?

Comment: @Malte you should probably edit that into your question.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks. Which fill mode did you apply to the second gradient?

Comment: @Malte its normal since the gradients second stop is 100 transparent. Note that technically this is still 2 objects just 1 for GUI purposes.

Comment: How did you set the fill to transparent?  Is it in a specific swatch some place?